# Newbie with Jenkinsfile

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to develop units test, and a Jenkins file to test the branches of the project.

My project has only master branch, I already have my pytest and my tox.ini which are working well.

Still after exploring the net, I'm having a lot of trouble with the jenkinsfile.

Thanks for reading and helping me :)

Jenkinsfile :

```
pipeline {
     agent any
     stages{
     stage('Build') {
         steps {
             sh 'echo "Hello World"'
             sh 'python --version'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'tox';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the error message i get :

```
Branch event

Obtained Jenkinsfile from fc799deffc59bd8b8645ecac20c3fc6f412f26c2

Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result

[Bitbucket] Build result notified

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkinsfile for class: groovy.lang.Binding

    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)

    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)

    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)

    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)

    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor95.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)

    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)

    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: tell us whats the problem, (what errors you getting)

Comment: edit your question and add it, delete these comments please, care for the right format

Comment: if this is your first time with pipeline I suggest you start simple [Creating a Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#creating-a-jenkinsfile) . This is a super simple Jenkinsfile, no python, no sh ... Its likely you just messed up your pipeline project configuration. Create a git project with only this file. This will help you work out any pipeline configuration issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like you are trying to access the Jenkinsfile but the file is not there? Is the file in another folder in you project? If yes, then you have to use the full path to the file!

Comment: The jenkinsfile is in the same folder than all my others files

Answer (score 0):

make sure you point your job to the correct folder where the Jenkinsfile is

[image]